# google oauth2 on android

Tags: java, android, google-api

I created a project via google api console, and follow the guides, I create a `OAuth Client ID` with `installed application` type.

> Client ID for installed applications
>
> Client ID:
>
> 12345667-sdfasdfk3jkfd8*3r2kjfj.apps.googleusercontent.com
> Redirect URIs: urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob
> http ://localhost
> Application type:  Android
> Package name:  com.example
> Certificate fingerprint (SHA1):  21:45:BD:F6:98:B8:71:50:39:BD:0E:83:F2:06:9B:ED:43:5A:C2:1C

Where is the `client secret`? And I do not find any sample code about how to use these data to setup an OAuth2 request. And I don't want to use `AccountManager`, because I cannot get `refreshToken`, which is needed by another service.

Answer (score 1):

The refresh_token is not available if you select "installed" as your application type.

If you need a refresh_token, select "web application" as your application type.

Comment: Hey @Chirag Shah, this used to work for me, but only a few days ago it stopped working and now it throws this error com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: Unknown. Any idea why? Is there something wrong with my scopes? https://gist.github.com/lawloretienne/7351151